# Issue with Bridging on cup handle

Tags: mesh

I've recently started learning Blender via BlenderGuru, but I've run into a problem I can't figure out. I'm working on a coffee cup handle, specifically attaching it at the bottom. He uses bridging for the edge loops, but on my model when I do that the vertices on the handle itself seem to bulge out. The merge option in the bridge seems to fix that, but then the connection to the cup itself gets these weird indentations that aren't present on the model in the video. Any thoughts on what I may be doing wrong?

Edit: here are some images of the issue
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vO6xy.jpg

Comment: Please share some images of the issue. I also recommend you to check other youtube tutorials about making a cups or mugs, they have great info too

Comment: @Emir I just added a few pictures, I hope that helps! I do plan on checking out more tutorials from others in the future, I just don't want to overload myself with information.